# In our IIS logs, why do requests last 5 min and longer when executionTimeout is 110 seconds?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, iis, iis-7.5

We're having some trouble with our server performance and while analyzing our IIS request logs we see lots of requests that take several **minutes** to complete.

How is this possible when the default value for `executionTimeout` in the ASP.NET `httpRuntime` settings element is **110 seconds**? From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) say about `executionTimeout` [emphasis mine]:

> Specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to execute before being automatically **shut down** by ASP.NET.

This is exactly the behavior we *would like to see* but below log entries make us believe that something is wrong and those requests are not terminated after the configured (or default) timeout:

[image: slowest requests]

I've also checked our code base for calls to `HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout` but there are only two of them that are executed in some rare cases and are assigned at most 600 (seconds).

Comment: We use an ElasticSearch node with Kibana as the frontend. That's where the screenshot is from. http://i.stack.imgur.com/efwWy.png load fine for me...

Comment: Great! For **get Slowest Requests**: `ElasticSearch node with Kibana`  is possible install in Windows Server ? Any ***tips and tricks*** about _ElasticSearch & Kibana_ configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say without knowing more about your app and environment. However, this link may help to explain why it can be higher than expected.

[Description of the time-taken field in IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 HTTP logging](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/944884)

Specifically:

> Beginning in IIS 6.0, the time-taken field typically includes network time. Before HTTP.sys logs the value in the time-taken field, HTTP.sys usually waits for the client to acknowledge the last response packet send operation or HTTP.sys waits for the client to reset the underlying TCP connection. Therefore, when a large response or large responses are sent to a client over a slow network connection, the value of the time-taken field may be more than expected.
>
> **Note** The value in the time-taken field does not include network time if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The response size is less than or equal to 2 KB, and the response size is from memory.
> - TCP buffering is used. Applications that use HTTPAPI.dll can set the HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_BUFFER_DATA flag to enable TCP buffering on
>   Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 and later. This allows the server
>   to send all of the response data to the client without having to wait
>   for the client’s corresponding acknowledgements.

Hope that helps.

Comment: do you know whether in ASP.NET WebForms, the second case in the **Note** section could be true? I'm trying to evaluate if your reference is really the cause of the problem.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not entirely sure. Here is an article that explains that setting a bit more... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2006/08/15/buffering-in-http-sys/. If I had to guess, I would say the application is dependent on how IIS is configured and that the app type (MVC or WebForms) doesn't bother by default.

Comment: Thanks for the link, found the same article, too. But I cannot find any hints on whether ASP.NET uses TCP buffering or not to send its responses...