# When executionTimeout is reached, what happens?

Tags: c#, iis, request

If the default is 110 seconds why do I see requests going beyond that (up to 177 seconds)? 
I'd expect and hope that once time is reached the request is cancelled and resources reallocated.

I'm seeing these response times in my apm tool (dynatrace) which instruments the code and doesn't likely get the time from the server logs

( referring to [In our IIS logs, why do requests last 5 min and longer when executionTimeout is 110 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115984/in-our-iis-logs-why-do-requests-last-5-min-and-longer-when-executiontimeout-is))

Thank you

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks MethodMan. My question would be is an exception thrown and the request is aborted? I'm seeing requests up to 177 seconds and no exceptions and my apm tool catches every exception.

Comment: I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170151/why-doesnt-my-action-method-time-out

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the requests may be being queued on the server? If you look at perfmon [RequestsQueued](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx) you might see some queuing going on.

Also look at request wait time to get an indication of how long the last request waited.

Comment: Thanks Avvi, I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170151/why-doesnt-my-action-method-time-out

Comment: Cool thanks for the update - glad you found an answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you send a screenshot of the PurePath showing the Exec Time but also the Elapsed Time column in the tree? Maybe the PurePath itself actually gets aborted by IIS after 110 s but some asynchronous activity in your ASP.NET App is still working and was not interrupted by the IIS Timeout. The PurePath tree should show that as it shows asynchronous subpaths
andi

Comment: just saw that you posted the same question on our dynatrace forum - here is the cross reference: https://answers.dynatrace.com/questions/159816/why-do-net-requests-run-longer-than-executiontimeo.html

Comment: Hey Andi, Thanks for replying, As this is sensitive information I created a ticket and attached the screen shot along with the exported pure path. The ticket number is 24690